# Invalid symlink "venv/bin/python3"

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to upload my Django code to Heroku but I am getting a build error:

```
=== Fetching app code failed.
=!= Invalid symlink "venv/bin/python3". Cannot point outside the working directory
```

My `Pipfile` is

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "~=3.1.0"
whitenoise = "==5.1.0"
gunicorn = "==19.9.0"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.8.5"
pillow = "==7.2.0"
django-debug-toolbar = "==2.2"
environs = {version = "==8.0.0", extras = ["django"]}
django-storages = "*"
boto3 = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Is anyone able to help me please?

Comment: Did you deploy with github?

Comment: Hi, yes I have deployed to GitHub.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, maybe it help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMbVzl_aLxM&ab_channel=PrettyPrinted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a virtual environment in a `venv/` subdirectory. This directory should *not* be pushed to Heroku (or committed at all).

Remove it from your repository, e.g. by doing something like

```
git rm -r --cached venv
git commit -m "Untrack virtual environment"
```

Then commit and push to GitHub or Heroku again, depending how you are deploying.

Answer (score -1):

I recently encountered this error. Just search for any symlinks anywhere in the project directory and try to remove them (since they may be pointing to some place on local)